# How to implement twitter-text-rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Hi I am trying use [twitter-text-rb](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb) gem.

added "include Twitter::Autolink" in application helper follow by example, after restarting the server getting error

Routing Error

```
uninitialized constant Twitter::Autolink
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-text'
```

And then run:

```
bundle install
```